# How do I assign an event to an input and checkbox made of n counts?

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, spring

I'm a `spring` beginner. I'm currently updating the data in `db`. The current `db` data I need is as follows.

```xml
        UPDATE
        MY_DB
        SET type_big_category = type_big_category
        <if test="status != ''">
        , status = #{status}
        </if>
        <if test="body != null">
        , body = #{body}
        </if>
        WHERE
        seq_no = #{seq_no}
```

And the list is being printed from `js file` by running a repeat statement.

```js
$(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url : "/dblistdata",
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "json",
        data: data,
        timeout: 10000
    }).done(function (result) {
        if(result.resultCode == "S000"){
            for (var i = 0; i < result.messagelist.length; i++) {
                var tableBody =  '<tr>'
                        + '<td>' + result.messagelist[i].type_big_category + '</td>'
                        + '<td>' + result.messagelist[i].type_mid_category + '</td>'
                        + '<td>'
                        + '<label class="checkbox" for="checkbox' + i + '">'
                        + '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox'+ i +'" id="checkbox' + i + '" onClick="checkBoxClick(this.name, '+ result.messagelist[i].seq_no +')" />' + '<i>' + '</i>'
                        + '</label>'
                        + '</td>'
                        + '<td>'
                        +   '<textarea class="form-control push-text">"' + result.messagelist[i].body + '"</textarea>'
                        + '</td>'
                        + '<td>'
                        +   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">save</button>'
                        +   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="deletebutton'+ i + '">delete</button>'
                        + '</td>'
                        + '</tr>';

                $('#tbody').append(tableBody);
                var btn[i] = document.getElementById('deletebutton[i]');
                btn[i].disabled = 'disabled';
            }
        }else{
            alert(result.resultMsg);
        }
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    })

});

function saveCommentData(seq_no, comment) {
    alert(seq_no);
}


function checkBoxClick(id, seq_no) {
    var data = {};
    data.seq_no = seq_no;
    console.log("id : " + id + " / seq_no " + seq_no);
    let check = $("#" + id).is(":checked");
    if (check == false) {
        var activecheck = confirm('Are you sure you want to disable it??');
        if (activecheck == true) {
            data.status = '0';
            updateStatus(data)
        } else {
            location.reload();
        }
    } else {
        var activecheck = confirm('Do you want to activate?');
        if (activecheck == true) {
            data.status = '1';
            updateStatus(data)
        } else {
            location.reload();
        }
    }
}

function updateStatus(data) {
    $.ajax({
        url : "/v1/point/admin/push/update_push_message_status",
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        data : data,
        success : function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    })
location.reload();
}
```

**jsp**

```
                                <form class="smart-form">
                                <table class="tb-regist" id="autoPushMsg">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>main</th>
                                            <th>sub</th>
                                            <th>check</th>
                                            <th colspan="2">mssage</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="tbody">
...
```

The blockage I have is `db`, the current `status` value is all 1 except one. Therefore, only one **check** should be disabled, and all the rest should be **checked**.

I must change the `body` value, i.e. the **message** value, and change the status when I press the Save button.

I'm done with the db design, but I don't know how to change the order and activate/disable the check.

Thank you for your help. I need your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The section on the indication of the check box status was resolved by inserting it into the repeat statement.

```js
                if(result.messagelist[i].status == '0') {
                    document.getElementById("checkbox" + i).checked = false;
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("checkbox" + i).checked = true;
                }
```

Thus, the check box status update function was completed and the index value of the corresponding row was received and resolved when the message value was updated.

```js
function saveCommentData(seq_no, index) {
    var activecheck = confirm('change message save?');
    var data = {}
    data.seq_no = seq_no;
    var comment = $("#comment" + index).val();
    data.body = comment
    if (activecheck == true) {
        updateStatus(data);
    } else {
        location.reload();
    }
}
```